# Finding median, dispersion and correlation coefficent of two random variables

Tags: random-variables, median, continuous-variables

Find median, dispersion and correlation coefficient of random variables A=X+2Y and B=Y. X and Y are both independent variables. X is a Poisson variable - X~P(2), Y is a continuous variable - Y~T(1, 6).

This is one of the exercises I can't get my head wrapped around from our statistics and probability theory course. This text was translated to the best of my efforts. From what I understand I must first find A and B independently and then find their median, etc.

If there's no possible answer for the oddly structured question, could I get a link to some other sources that find medians, dispersions and/or correlation coefficients of random variables with different types - for example X being Poisson and Y being continuous? Different types like normalised or geometrical would do as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the distribution T(1,6)?